# Put icon inside input element in a form and move the icon

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I put in input icon and i am trying to move it.

From:

[image: first] 
to
[image: second]

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Въведе потребителско име ...">
```

CSS

```
#contact input[name='username']{
    background:url('../image/icon/user.png'), #ebebeb;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    background-position: right;
    width: 355px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right:55px;
    border: 0px;  
    margin-top: 6px;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s;
}
```

Comment: you can try add that space in your image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
background-position: 0 5px 0 0;
```

instead of

```
background-position: right;
```

Comment: Thanks for this i fix it with background-position: 380px 2px;

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your CSS code

```
margin-right:10px;
```